# com.googlecode.json-simple & Java Streams not working together

Tags: java, json, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm having trouble getting [com.googlecode.json-simple](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1) and Java-8 streams to work together.

The following code is not working:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
List<String> a = jsonArray.stream()
        .map(o -> ((Map)o).get("s"))
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It says :

```
java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

But it should work as I'm explicitly typecasting the stream objects to `String`, before collecting.

Comment: Did you notice that I mentioned an assumption `jsonArray` to be a `List<Object>` in the answer? Anyway what makes you do `jsonArray.stream()` otherwise?

Comment: Because JSONArray extends `list` internally. And it is unparameterized, hence the problem

Comment: You're right. My bad to have missed the `extends` part. That could certainly bring in a lot of unchecked cast warnings. But iterating on index if you're sure of the JSON being a list could possibly do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Since `JSONArray` extends `ArrayList` but doesn't bind type to it, one way to do that possibly would be to iterate the list on index instead as:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
List<String> list = IntStream.range(0, jsonArray.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> ((Map) jsonArray.get(i)).get("s"))
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Have you tested it? I just did & it's not working. Giving same compilation error

Comment: @PankajSinghal Well, I compiled it for now. Haven't tested against any actual JSON data though.

Comment: @PankajSinghal Well, it's mostly from the fact that because of the raw type conversion `collect` is not able to infer the return type. If you instead try and break your code into pieces as `Stream<String> a = jsonArray.stream()
            .map(o -> ((Map) o).get("s"))
            .map(Object::toString);` which is explicitly casting the `Stream` to `Stream<String>` and then collect `List<String> res = a.collect(Collectors.toList());` it would still compile. But note possibly for the unchecked call to `map` its result might be erased as well in this case.